# What are the conditions under which these equations hold for dielectric and magnetic materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

$E_0 = \frac{D}{\varepsilon_0}$,  $E' = -\frac{P}{\varepsilon_0}$
$B_0 = \mu_0 \cdot H$,  $B' = \mu_0 \cdot M$
（$E_0$ refers to the electric field generated by free charges, or the external electric field, while $B_0$ denotes the external magnetic field; $E'$ refers to the electric field generated by polarized charges, and $B'$ refers to the magnetic field generated by magnetization currents.）
These equations seem to hold in most cases, but there are exceptions (e.g., a dielectric sphere uniformly polarized in a uniform electric field).
My textbook tells me that these expressions hold under certain conditions, but it is not clear about the conditions. Could you please explain in detail?
(My English is poor, if there's any language mistake I apologize)

example:in a uniformly polarized dielectric ball, $E' = -\frac{P}{3ε_0}$
[image: dielectric ball]
while in a parallel plate capacitor or a charged metal sphere immersed in an infinite dielectric medium, $E_0 = \frac{D}{ε_0}$ and $E' = -\frac{P}{ε_0}$
[image: parallel plate capacitor]
[image: metal sphere]

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I don't think your notation is widely known;  I've never seen $E'$ and $B'$ have some standard definition in the context of EM fields in a medium.  You could certainly *define* quantities this way but I have no idea what their physical significance could be.  Can you [edit your question] to provide more context on the physical meaning and significance of these quantities?

Comment: @Michael Seifert Thanks! I have added their meanings

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'm worried I didn't use @ correctly so I tried again sorry